# How does matlab solve a differential equation?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, numerical-analysis

This question is not about how to use matlab, but trying to find out what is happening when matab is solving a differential equation. Results are often different when using different numerical methods. i wonder which numerical method is used in matlab.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab has all kinds of numerical solvers available. The basic set can be found at the bottom of this page:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html

If you'd like to know about a particular solver (say ode45) you can scroll to the bottom of the documentation for the given solver (for ode45 it's found here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html). For this solver the paper which explains it is linked. It may, however, be a little obtuse if you are unfamiliar with the general idea behind numerical solvers, so you might consider checking out a more pedagogical text in this area, such as the one at http://numerical.recipes/. You may also consider googling less complicated solvers like the Euler Method or the Runge-Kutta method -- both give you the flavor for how the numerical solvers work.